# When inserting scripts from Google API does the user download multiple times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-api

When using the following source to add AJAX capabilities to my website I'm afraid the user might have to download the script several times, since I'm not certain where it's stored on the client PC and how long it'll stay there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Would it be a good idea to create a condition to check for this link's download status and have a backup on my server just in case, and how would you do that? I'm working in PHP, but still a novice and don't know what function I'd use to check the download status with.

While I'm asking, what do you consider the biggest advantages of the AJAX library, I'm familiar with the asynchronous call to the server or even other websites, but what else puts AJAX ahead in regards to client-side scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those api developers take care of client side caching, well. Second thing is you may serve them from server of your own, but all caching headers to be taken care by you. Lastly, the api developers' servers are more equipped with large set of CDN ( content distribution networks ), and you may never know how you can deliver a file faster than they do.

My recommendation is just include those files from where they are. ( as the url provided from them ). *replace leading // to http*